# UrlMappings to point a URL to an asset pipeline file in Grails

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, url-mapping, grails-3.0, urlmappings.groovy

In Grails 3.0 how do you map a URL to a file under the `assets` folder?

For example:
`http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico` --> `grails-app/assets/images/bookmark.ico`

I've tried a few test mappings, such as:

**grails-app/controllers/UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {
      ...
      "/t1.png"  (uri: "/assets/images/test.png")
      "/t2.png"  (uri: "/assets/test.png")
      "/t3.png"  (uri: "/images/test.png")
      "/t4.png"  (dir: "assets/images", file: "test.png")
      ...
      }

}
```

...but they all result in a 500 server error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to map the URL to AssetController of the Asset Plugin, like this (not tested):

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {

    ...

    "/files/$id"  (controller :"AssetController", action:"index") 
       ...
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but it seems to only result in 404s (I additionally tried various other permutations using `AssetController` with no success).  Do you have a specific working example?

Comment: Actually not, that was just an idea. I had a short look at the `AssetController` an thought that could work... Maybe a look into the `AssetTagLib` helps you to understand the `AssetPlugin` and you can write your own Controller that the things you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Asset-Pipeline you can map static resources to URLs by following the steps laid out in the [Grails Documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings). However your question is asking how to map a single resource to a single URL with the [Asset-Pipeline plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline).

Burt Beckwith provided insight on the [Grails forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/url-mapping-to-image-td4636402.html) a few years ago about Grail's role in serving static resources.

> Grails doesn't serve static resources, the container does. So there's no way to directly configure a mapping - you need to serve it through a controller or configure a proxy as Eric suggests.
>
> Burt

This answer may be unsatisfying. But if you must serve a static resource and absolutely do not want to use a controller or proxy you can try the following.

Create a view called image.gsp. The view will only contain an asset tag. Using your examples above,

```
<asset:image src="t1.png"/>
```

Then configure your URL mappings to point to the `image.gsp` page.

```
class UrlMappings {

   static mappings = {
      ...
      "/t1.png"  (view: "image")
      ...
      }

}
```

I recognize this may not be the exact method you were hoping to use. But I think that understanding the role Grails plays vs. the container running Grails will help inform a decision to properly serve a resource to the user.

I know this may seem unrelated but if you want to create a page that lists the contents of a directory check out this [post by CodePanda](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/a-simple-grails-controller-for-file-management/). His code can be used as a template to create a controller to serve a single file and he explains how to update the view, controller, and groovy.config.

Comment: Does this solution actually work?  It looks very similar to `"/t3.png"  (uri: "/images/test.png")` from the original question, and that does not work for me.  Note that the question is about mapping a URL (**singular**) to a file (**singular**).

Comment: I verified that it worked. Try mapping to a file outside of the asset folder. Place it in the grails project directory and see if you can map a URL to it.

Comment: What URL did you use?  (note: mapping to a file outside of the `assets` folder is of no value as then you don't even need the mapping.)

Comment: The updated answer of using `<asset:image src="t1.png"/>` inside a GSP has the effect of displaying an image, but it looks like the HTTP response is technically HTML (`Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8`).  This solution may work for certain use cases, but it would not be applicable where the image file itself is required.

Answer (score -1):

Using `"/favicon.ico"(uri: "/assets/favicon.ico")` works for me.

Conceptually, it appears that Asset Pipeline flattens the assets (so that you do not need to specity `images`, `javascripts`, `stylesheets` for the `uri`)

Grails: `3.2.11`
AssetPipeline: `2.14.6`