# Rendering static file as URI in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

In Grails 2.x, the following works:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        /**
         * Serving the index.html directly
         */
        "/"(uri: "/ng/app/index.html")
    }
}
```

Given that there is a `index.html` file available in `web-app/ng/app/` directory. Now when we browse the URL `http://localhost:8080` in Grails 2, the `index.html` renders automatically.

In Grails 3, I added the same `index.html` file in `src/main/webapp/`, I can properly browse the same like `http://localhost:8080/static/index.html`.

So, I'm trying to do the same in `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        /**
         * Serving the index.html directly
         */
        "/"(uri: "/static/index.html")
    }
}
```

But this is giving me error `{"message":"Internal server error","error":500}`:

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - UrlMappingException occurred when processing request: [GET] /
Unable to establish controller name to dispatch for [null]. Dynamic closure invocation returned null. Check your mapping file is correct, when assigning the controller name as a request parameter it cannot be an optional token!. Stacktrace follows:
grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Unable to establish controller name to dispatch for [null]. Dynamic closure invocation returned null. Check your mapping file is correct, when assigning the controller name as a request parameter it cannot be an optional token!
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've create my app with Grails 3.1.8 Angular profile and later removed Angular related stuff like Grails GSP plugin, Asset pipeline etc.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441643/urlmappings-to-point-a-url-to-an-asset-pipeline-file-in-grails

Comment: Thanks @DrewBeres for replying. I already knew this solution and I've another way of serving the static content via file stream but unfortunately I want that solution to work like Grails 2.5.4

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an open issue with Grails 3, slated to be resolved for Grails 3.2.0.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9908

Answer (score 1):

As of `Grails 3.x's` implementation of URLMapping handler, you can only specify `controller`, `view` or a `redirect` in your URL mappings. As such your `uri` is going to fail as it does not map to any controller or view.

Though after tinkering with the source code, I found a workaround that may come in handy for your use case here. You can actually issue a `redirect` here because redirect will be able to handle `uri`.

So, your `URLMappings.groovy` should be like -->

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        /**
        * Serving the index.html directly
        */
        "/"(redirect: [uri: "/static/index.html"])
    }
}
```

This code works fine for me with `Grails 3.1.8`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working for me. It is still redirecting me to the `/static/index.html` instead of serving `index.html` directly.

Comment: As of now, you can't simply serve static files this way. But if you use the  `redirect` with `uri`, it will serve without throwing the exception you were getting. This is just a workaround if you want to do the same using URLMapping.

Comment: Oh! I though your workaround is not for redirecting. This is already working for me as `"/"(redirect: '/ng/app/index.html')`

Comment: Exactly, this will at least save us from using a controller just to serve index page if our application is SPA